# Regex: How to get all words, special characters and white spaces between quotation marks?

Tags: regex

Currently I have a regex expression `([^\[\][\[^\[\][\n"]+)` to match text between `""`, but this does not capture whitespaces, for e.g. if I enter `" hello "`, it will return `hello`, without the spaces before and after the word.

Is there some expression I can use to just simply catch anything between two quotation marks?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help:

```
(?<!\\)(\"|')(.+?)(?:(?<!\\)\1)
```

And to get the text inside the quotes, get the second capture group.

[Proof.](https://regex101.com/r/UbRKkP/1)

### Explanation

`(?<!\\)` - Negative lookbehind. Looks for literal backslash ('')

`(\"|')` - to test for the start of the "string"

`(.+?)`  - `.` will match **anything *but* newlines**.
`+?` means as much as possible but only as much needed to match.

`(?:(?<!\\)\1)` - Non capturing group.
Used here so we can use the `(?<!\\)` described earlier without looking behind the whole expression. The

`\1` matches the first capture group (`(\"|')`). Can be replaced with `$1`

Comment: It shows that I have an invalid syntax while trying to apply it? Also how do I get the second capture group, kinda new to regex :)

Comment: Are you using python? What flavor of regex? did you escape the strings? @Blade

Comment: Yeah i'm using python 3.7.2 and I think it's the default flavor and I have no clue on escaping strings. I'm using the SLY module to try and build a lexer and parser but there's not much documentation with it

Comment: @Blade Hey! I'm making a lexer/parser too! Just do ```import re; STRING = re.compile(r"(?<!\\)(\"|')(.+?)(?:(?<!\\)\1)")``` and then use `STRING.search` or `STRING.match` to search/match

Comment: What module are you using to make your lexer/parser, if any, because in SLY it requires you to specify a regex expression to find text, if you don't then it flags them up as illegal characters, so searching the string for a match won't work because it doesn't give me anything to search :/

Comment: I'm not using SLY. I'm using pure python. I'm writing it myself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220183/discussion-between-blade-and-thex).

Answer (score 1):

You should use following regex:

```
\"\s*([^\"]+?)\s*\"
```

`([^\"]+?)`The text you want to get will be between space and quote.

[Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/SwxrV9/4/)

Comment: Doesn't match `'this string'`